# data reading from text file and writing

Tags: python, file

I have text file containing data like

ramesh

3.7

shyam

3.2

hari

3.0

manish

4.0

as name and GPA scores i need to display and write it to another text file in format like

NAME          SCORE

Ramesh           3.7

shyam            3.2

hari             3.0

manish           4.0

and another format like :

NAME  ramesh   shyam   hari   manish

marks  3.7      3.2     3.0     4.0

the code I used to separe is as follos

```
infile = open("data.txt", "r")

names = []
marks= []
odd_lines = []
even_lines = []
for odd_line, even_line in zip(infile, infile):
    odd_lines.append(odd_line.rstrip('\n'))
    even_lines.append(even_line.rstrip('\n'))

names = odd_lines
marks = even_lines
```

but i am unable to display and wrtie in required format..anhy help please

Comment: added the code that writes data to file.

Answer (score 0):

The format that you used could be improved with something like:
NAME, MARKS

But if you want a solution for this format, try and use something like:

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as file:
  names = file.read().splitlines()[::2]
  marks = file.read().splitlines()[1::2]
  namesNmarks = list(zip(names, marks))
for name, marks in namesNmarks:
  print(f"{name}: {marks}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 import numpy as np

 NEWDATA = np.loadtxt('data.txt', dtype=str) 
 np.savetxt('data_reshaped.txt', NEWDATA.reshape(-1, 2), fmt='%s')
```